# MySQL functions not working when PHP script is called from exec()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP script I execute in the background from an exec call. Everything works except for the MySQL functions (they don't exist). If I call the script directly from the browser it works fine. What's happening here? Any ideas?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 3):

Either your command line php was not compiled with php, or php.ini for your command line php does not have the mysql driver module loaded. You'll need to reconfigure and/or rebuild your php installation.

Answer (score 2):

Probably, `php_mysql.so` is not enabled in your main `php.ini` but is enabled in an additional ini file added to `Apache` with `PHPIniDir`.

Compare output of `phpinfo()` called from the command line and from a web script. You should see the difference between the ini files and directories used.